# R: Using dplyr to filter out a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm new to R and I'm having trouble filtering out my dataframe for a specific condition. For some reason, the code is working and I'm not getting any errors but when I view the updated dataframe... the condition I set didn't excute.

The condition that isn't excuting is the var>50.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code so far:

```
if (!require(pacman)) {
  install.packages('pacman')

}

pacman::p_load("ggplot2", "tidyr", "plyr", "dplyr")
#### Read in the necessary data ######
roadsalt_data <- read.table("QADportaldata_1988-2015.tsv", header = T, sep = "\t", fill = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
# Convert date column from a character class to a date class so ggplot can  display as a continuous variable ###
roadsalt_data$stdate <- as.Date(roadsalt_data$stdate)
## Filter dataset to only contain columns I need ########
filtered_roadsalt <- roadsalt_data %>% 
  select(orgid, stdate, locid, charnam, val) %>%
  filter(between(stdate, as.Date("1996-01-01"), as.Date("2015-07-01"))) %>%
  filter(charnam == "Total dissolved solids" & "var" > 50)
```

Preview of my dataset:

```
'data.frame':   47850 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ orgid  : chr  "USGS-NJ" "USGS-NJ" "USGS-NJ" "USGS-NJ" ...
 $ stdate : Date, format: "2014-03-05" "2014-03-05" "2014-03-04" ...
 $ locid  : chr  "USGS-01367785" "USGS-01367785" "USGS-01455099" "USGS-01455099" ...
 $ charnam: chr  "Total dissolved solids" "Total dissolved solids" "Total dissolved solids" "Total dissolved solids" ...
 $ val    : chr  "0.21" "154" "0.43" "333" ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming class(val) is a factor, then condition in filter has to be this way:

```
filter(charnam == "Total dissolved solids" & as.numeric(as.character(val)) > 50.00)
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much... I hope in the future to not make such rookie mistakes haha

Answer (score 2):

When using dplyr functions, you don't need quotes around your variable names. So,

```
filter(charnam == "Total dissolved solids" & "var" > 50)
```

should be replaced with

```
filter(charnam == "Total dissolved solids" & var > 50)
```

Var also has to be converted to a numeric variable.

That being said, if you `select` at the beginning of your pipe, you have to include all the variables on which you want to add filters. Because  you haven't selected a variable called "var" in your initial `select` statement, so you won't be able to filter on `var`. If that's meant to be 'val', then you're good to go.